# ggplot facet_wrapping multiple dataframes in one step [r]

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I would like to ask is it possible to `facet_wrap` one dataframe before and after transformation of data using still one step?

I provide example here:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

A <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gear, qsec)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = gear)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~"Before")


# Removing outliers using Inter quantile ranger

B <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  mutate(
    Q1 = quantile(qsec)[[2]],
    Q2 = quantile(qsec)[[3]],
    Q3 = quantile(qsec)[[4]],
    IQR = Q3 - Q1, 
    MIN = Q1 - 1.5*IQR,
    MAX = Q3 + 1.5*IQR) %>% 
  filter(
    qsec >= MIN,
    qsec <= MAX) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gear, qsec)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = gear), outlier.colour = NA) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~"After Outlier remov")



grid.arrange(A, B)
```

Is it possible to replicate this using just `ggplot` and not `gridextra`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` and a few tweaks and adds to your code, you can work around your problem by creating a large data.frame combining A's and B's data.frames as follows:

```
# Creating A's dataframe and adding id column named `set`

auxA <- 
  mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(set="Before")


# Creating B's dataframe and adding id column named `set`. 
# Then removing outliers using Inter quantile ranger

auxB <- 
  mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(set="After Outlier remov")  %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  mutate(
    Q1 = quantile(qsec)[[2]],
    Q2 = quantile(qsec)[[3]],
    Q3 = quantile(qsec)[[4]],
    IQR = Q3 - Q1, 
    MIN = Q1 - 1.5*IQR,
    MAX = Q3 + 1.5*IQR) %>% 
  filter(
    qsec >= MIN,
    qsec <= MAX) %>% 
  ungroup() 

# auxA and auxB differ in number of columns so we use bind_rows() to bind them instead of rbind()

df <- dplyr::bind_rows(auxA,auxB)

# Reworking variable "set" as factor with an specific level order

df$set <- factor(df$set, levels = unique(df$set))

# Plotting df "set" for faceting and fixing outlier's color black

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gear, qsec)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = gear), outlier.colour = "black") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(set), nrow = 2)
```

The result:

[image]

By setting up outlier's color = black for all the graph, outliers do appear in what would be you "B" plot (but I'm guessing you were already aware of that)...

Hope it helps though

Comment: Hi thank you, however this is not examply it. When you remove outliers median and IQR will change, that is why we see outlies event in the second boxplots. I need first one to show outlies and second one to not.

Comment: That's what I thought. The problem Is that -to my knowledge- `facet_wrap` is not going to let you treat each facet differently. What might be interesting for you is to check out to what measure you may introduce modifications on a concrete facet with `ggplot_build()`